# My icon of the coderunner in VS code is not showing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Today I installed VS code to learn python. I installed **Code Runner** extension and some how I disabled the 'run' icon which is shown in the top right corner. I have been trying for several hours. How can I get it back again?

[image: My Home page of VS]

I tried to schange the settings. But the icon is not coming. I know that `ctrl+alt+N` runs the code.But I need the icon back.

Comment: Have you tried restarting vscode? Can you show your settings.json (ctrl+shift+p --> `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`)?

Comment: Does the icon appear? Did my answer help you?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still stumbling. My settings.json:
{ "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
    "gitlens.defaultDateLocale": "system",
    "gitlens.defaultDateFormat": null,
    "gitlens.defaultDateShortFormat": null,
    "gitlens.defaultTimeFormat": null,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "editor.minimap.size": "fit",
    "editor.minimap.showSlider": "always"}

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + P  --> Open Settings.` There are two settings.json file [here](https://i.imgur.com/MsB4ZYD.png) (workspace and user), can you show the content of these two files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't installed Microsoft's official [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension. It is officially recommended to use the python extension to run python code.

The **Code Runner** extension you install can also run multiple languages. After looking around I found such a setting that controls whether the "Run Code" icon is displayed in the editor header menu.

```json
    "code-runner.showRunIconInEditorTitleMenu": true
```

[image]

Please check in your **settings.json** if this setting exists and it is set to `false`. If so, please modify the value to `true`. If not, add it and set it to `true`.

Finally, I still recommend that you download and use the **Python** extension. **Code Runner** can be used as an auxiliary.

Comment: I just checked that, the icon is showing for other windows except the python file.
If the file is PHP or other extensions it is all right.

Answer (score 0):

It was hidden in my case as well.

In the upper right corner of your editor you should see three dots. Click the dots, and select the option `run or debug`.

[image: dot menu]

You should now be able to see the code runner button in the titlebar.